# How to do basic authentication using cookies in spring security?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cookies, spring-security

I am securing my REST api using Basic-Auth. On correct credentials passed by user, a controller is responsible for sending a `httpOnly` and `secure` cookie in response.

```
@GetMapping
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.OK)
public void loginUser( final HttpServletRequest request ,final HttpServletResponse response) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    setAuthCookieToResonse(request,response);

}

private void setAuthCookieToResonse(final HttpServletRequest request ,final HttpServletResponse response) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String cookieKey = "auth";
    String cookieValue = request.getHeader("Authorization");

    if (cookieValue != null) {
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie(cookieKey, cookieValue);
        cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
        cookie.setSecure(true);

        response.addCookie(cookie);
    }
}
```

So, now with each request a cookie is being sent by the browser, which will contain Basic-Auth details. But the problem is, how do the spring security extract those credentials from that cookie?

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {// @formatter:off 
        httpSecurity
        .cors()
        .and().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/signup/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().httpBasic()
        .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and().csrf().disable()
        ;
     }
```

My guess was:
To add a filter before `BasicAuthenticationFilter.class` and extract the credentials from `cookie` and than add those credentials to the `HttpServletRequest`'s `Authorizaton` header which is going to be passed to spring-security layer. But the problem is, `HttpServletRequest` doesn't have API to add headers.

What would be the right way to implement this?

Comment: @dur Added a solution. Would love to hear from you, if you have some improvement suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made this working after following [this blog (archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160710105752/https://wilddiary.com/adding-custom-headers-java-httpservletrequest/). But I would love to hear **other solutions, especially using some spring configuration** itself. Spring is a very matured framework, it must(should) have something to handle this common problem.

Since, the `HttpServletRequest` don't have any method to add the new headers, I need to create a custom class which can add new headers to the request, this can be achived by `HttpServletRequestWrapper`. Here is the implementation.

```
public final class MutableHttpServletRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    // holds custom header and value mapping
    private final Map<String, String> customHeaders;

    public MutableHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
        this.customHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }

    public void putHeader(String name, String value) {
        this.customHeaders.put(name, value);
    }

    public String getHeader(String name) {
        // check the custom headers first
        String headerValue = customHeaders.get(name);

        if (headerValue != null) {
            return headerValue;
        }
        // else return from into the original wrapped object
        return ((HttpServletRequest) getRequest()).getHeader(name);
    }

    public Enumeration<String> getHeaderNames() {
        // create a set of the custom header names
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(customHeaders.keySet());

        // now add the headers from the wrapped request object
        Enumeration<String> e = ((HttpServletRequest) getRequest()).getHeaderNames();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            // add the names of the request headers into the list
            String n = e.nextElement();
            set.add(n);
        }

        // create an enumeration from the set and return
        return Collections.enumeration(set);
    }
}
```

The filter which checks for the cookie, before the Spring-secuirty:

```
public class CheckAuthCookieFilter implements Filter {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        MutableHttpServletRequest mutableRequest = new MutableHttpServletRequest(httpServletRequest);

        Cookie[] cookies = httpServletRequest.getCookies();

        if (cookies != null && cookies.length > 0) {
            for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                logger.debug(cookie.getName() + " : " + cookie.getValue());
                if (cookie.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("auth")) {
                    mutableRequest.putHeader("Authorization", URLDecoder.decode(cookie.getValue(), "utf-8"));
                }
            }
        }

        chain.doFilter(mutableRequest, response);

    }

}
```

and finally the security configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {// @formatter:off 
    httpSecurity
    .cors()
    .and().authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/signup/**").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and().httpBasic()
    .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    .and().csrf().disable()
    ;
    
    httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(new CheckAuthCookieFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class); 

}
```

My custom filter will run before the Spring's `BasicAuthenticationFilter`.If there is a cookie present with name `auth`(which the application created on successful login), than that's the cookie which holds the basic auth credentials. The credentials are extracted from that, and added to the header of `request`. Then the `BasicAuthenticationFilter` will run and look for the `Authorization` and proceed with its normal flow.

Comment: I think there is no spring way and this java servlet path seems as a neath integration into spring.