# Spring boot HttpSecurity : My filter is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I started a filter that I found on the internet to detect if the person is connected or not but it does not work when I go to the page which one must be identified to access it it gives me access denied.

Here is my code :

```
public final class MutableHttpServletRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
// holds custom header and value mapping
private final Map<String, String> customHeaders;

public MutableHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    super(request);
    this.customHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();
}

public void putHeader(String name, String value) {
    this.customHeaders.put(name, value);
}

public String getHeader(String name) {
    // check the custom headers first
    String headerValue = customHeaders.get(name);

    if (headerValue != null) {
        return headerValue;
    }
    // else return from into the original wrapped object
    return ((HttpServletRequest) getRequest()).getHeader(name);
}

public Enumeration<String> getHeaderNames() {
    // create a set of the custom header names
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(customHeaders.keySet());

    // now add the headers from the wrapped request object
    Enumeration<String> e = ((HttpServletRequest) getRequest()).getHeaderNames();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        // add the names of the request headers into the list
        String n = e.nextElement();
        set.add(n);
    }

    // create an enumeration from the set and return
    return Collections.enumeration(set);
}
```

Class CheckAuthCookieFilter

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    MutableHttpServletRequest mutableRequest = new MutableHttpServletRequest(httpServletRequest);

    Cookie[] cookies = httpServletRequest.getCookies();

    if (cookies != null && cookies.length > 0) {
        for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {                
            if (cookie.getName().equals("user-id")) {
                
                mutableRequest.putHeader(cookie.getValue(), URLDecoder.decode(cookie.getValue(), "utf-8"));
                
            }
        }
    }

    chain.doFilter(mutableRequest, response);

}
```

Class SecurityConfig

class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

    /*
     * httpSecurity.cors().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").
     * permitAll().and().httpBasic().and() .csrf().disable();
     * httpSecurity.headers().frameOptions().disable();
     */

    httpSecurity.cors().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/Users/login").permitAll().anyRequest()
            .authenticated().and().httpBasic().and().sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().csrf().disable();

    httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(new CheckAuthCookieFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

}
```

Could you please help me.

Comment: Please, provide us where you got this code from. Anyway it looks like you never authorize your user in filter. You could use for example `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);` to set a current logged user.

Comment: here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54609570/how-to-do-basic-authentication-using-cookies-in-spring-security

Comment: Since you don't manage Security Context on your own and delegate it to the filters, please, check the documentation first. In your case you're putting `cookie.getValue()` as header name, but in SecurityConfig class put it before BasicAuthenticationFilter class. This class is trying to log in user using credentials in "Authorization" header, but i guess `cookie.getValue()` is not a constant value with content of 'Authorization'. For further information look:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/www/BasicAuthenticationFilter.html